# Efficient data export from multiple databases to CSV using Java

Tags: java, batch-processing

I have a unique requirement to fetch selected records and columns from two different databases - one in SQL Server and the other in MongoDB. The goal is to store this data into a file, and I'm looking for an efficient Java-based solution or reference code to accomplish this task quickly. I'm relatively new to Java, and the data volume is substantial, approximately 3 million records. Since this isn't a recurring job, I'd prefer not to use ETL tools. Instead, I want a utility that can read and export large amounts of data multiple times into a CSV file.

When I manually export data from SQL Server, it takes a few minutes, and I'm wondering if there's a quicker way to achieve this using Java, perhaps by leveraging multiple threads or other optimization techniques. Any guidance, code snippets, or references would be greatly appreciated